# Linker File Problem

Tags: pic, bootloader, mplab, linker

I am dealing with a problem in my application with the linker file. 
What's happening is in the explorer tab it seems the linker file it's not "selected"

[image: Linker file issue]

I have to refer that I also have a bootloader.
I'm getting an error of "(944) data conflict at address 1FC02FF8h" and I think it's related with that. Can anyone help me on that? Many Thanks.